# Человек года 2016

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Как правильно писать и произносить **"Человек года 2016"**? В Нацкорпусе есть варианты с пробелом и дефисом, а на мой взгляд надо бы поставить тире. Ведь 2016 - это неизменяемое приложение, относящееся к сочетанию "человек года".

Из Нацкорпуса:

Председатель комитета культуры администрации Старорусского муниципального района Елена Иванова удостоена звания **«Человек года 2012»**. [Алиса Селезнева. За большую работу (2013.03.29) // «Новгородские ведомости», 2013]

24 декабря минувшего года Евгению Наздратенко в Москве в храме Христа Спасителя вручили национальную премию **«Человек года-2002»** с формулировкой «За отстаивание экономических интересов России». [Борьба за рыбу в воде (2003) // «Рыбак Приморья», 2003.01.09]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Корректно:  "Человек года — 2016 Но: **Сочи-2014 (неизменяемое приложение, передаваемое на письме цифрами, присоединяется дефисом).**

В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире.
В сочетаниях с цифровыми обозначениями, если цифре предшествует часть, содержащая пробел, напр.: операция «Меченые атомы — 2», сценарий фильма «Место встречи изменить нельзя — 2» (ср. фильм «Спрут-5»).

См.:[Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник
Корректирующие правила, §154.](http://www.e-reading.by/book.php?book=143269)

Comment: А если не содержит пробела, напр. "Человек-паук... 9"? На мой взгляд, и здесь требуется противопоставление числа составному понятию при помощи тире ("Мини-бикини - '69" и т. .п). По какой-то причине в "корректирующем правиле" фигурирует "цифра", а не число, одной цифрой ограничены и имеющиеся примеры. В случае же с годом для тире достаточно общих соображений: дефис связал бы число лишь с отдельным словом, разбив составное понятие, а пробел (ввиду несогласованности падежа) создаёт возможность неверного прочтения ("... года 2016-го") - остаётся верный вариант с тире.

Comment: @   Alex_ander, хотя в правилах об этом ничего не сказано, но думаю, что по аналогии с этим правилом нужно тире.  В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей в свою очередь является сочетанием с приложением и содержит дефис, напр.: рассказ о студенте-медике — альпинисте; встреча с приятелем — шахматистом-любителем; у соседа — писателя-фантаста. Ср. студент-альпинист, сосед-писатель.